# How to get Application Path in Tomcat (not from a Servlet context)

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, tomcat7

What I need is very simple, but the solutions posted here do not apply to my specific case.
It seems it's possible to get `catalina.base` and from that guess your applications directory by following `/webapps/<application_name>`.

As already pointed out in the question's title, I'm not in Servlet context here, but in a regular class.

I think that works in most cases within a standard Tomcat installation. But from within an IDE, where the directories are all separated (source code, build, catalina base, etc) it doesn't really work. In NetBeans, for example, `catalina.base` is NOT where the application is located.

What I want is to be able to guess the application directory so as to guess it's log files subdir. So in my local environment (NetBeans) I have /webapps/App/logs and anywhere else I would also have /webapps/App/logs.

What I can't seem to find is a sure way to fetch "whateverdir". Any ideas?

Comment: On a side note.  I would not put your logs in a directory beneath the app unless you want them to be public.

Comment: I would not either. But I have to as it's the standard for webapps here, and I don't really have a say in it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Define a servlet that loads on startup.  In its init() method use the "catalina.base" approach to get the directory.
2. After you get the directory, save the value in a system property.
3. Then in your non-servlet code, simply read the system property.

Comment: Cool idea. Will try it! :)